# Send websocket request from Django

Tags: python, django, websocket

Here is my deal:

- I have a websocket pubsub server written in python with autobahn websocket (based on twisted).
- I have simple website that is connected to the server and subscribed to one channel
- Next to this I have simple Django project with one app
- And at last I have opened terminal with curl get request that hits my Django app

After request form curl hits my django app and my view I need to send message to the server to the channel that my website is subscribed on. Basically I need websocket client that can send message to specific channel and can be run in django view (no infinite blocking loop).

I've tried to figure out this over 4 days. I've wrote to writ autobahn pubsub client with twisted.reacotr, but I can send the message only once (after I stop reactor to finish django request I cannot start it again, because it's not restartable).

I've olso tried djagno-socketio, but there is but, so I cannot see clients when I try to send the message from django view.

ws4py doesn't support channels

Thanks for any advice. Great would be an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use autobahn.ws with django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999970/how-to-use-autobahn-ws-with-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to run Django and Autobahn within 1 server:

Here is an [example](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/websocket/echo_wsgi) that shows how to use Flask/WSGI with Autobahn. And Django can run in a WSGI container [as well](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/).

Also it should be possible to run an Autobahn-based WebSocket client from a Django/WSGI/Twisted based server using above method as well.

The point is: Twisted can act as a WSGI container and will then run the WSGI Web app (which can be blocking) on a background pool of worker threads. This will allow you to use the asynch features of Twisted, and e.g. run Autobahn - either client or server. So you might also rethink the overall architecture: why run the Autobahn server as a different process at all?