# How to use autobahn.ws with django?

Tags: python, django, websocket, autobahn

Need for websockets in my project. Found out crossplatform solution [autobahn.ws](http://autobahn.ws) but only tutorial for pure python is available. How to use autobahn as chat server in django project?

Answer (score 5):

Simply add the following bit of code to the python script where you setup your websocket.

```
if __name__ == '__main__': #pragma nocover
    # Setup environ
    sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
    import django
    django.setup()
```

Now your code that creates a web socket can make use of django models and other features just as if it was a view.